# How to sort embedded list of dictionary by key value?

Tags: python, sorting

For below embedded list of dictionary, how to sort it according to key1 path's string length?

```
jobs = [ {"key1":"path/123", "key2":list1}, \
         {"key1":"path/12",  "key2":list2}, \ 
         {"key1":"path/1",   "key2":list3} ]
```

Expected output

```
sorted_jobs = [ {"key1":"path/1",   "key2":list3}  \
                {"key1":"path/12",  "key2":list2}, \ 
                {"key1":"path/123", "key2":list1} ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define the `key` function in `sorted`:

```
sorted_jobs = sorted(jobs, key=lambda d: len(d['key1']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `key` parameter of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
res = sorted(jobs, key=lambda x: len(x["key1"]))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'key1': 'path/1', 'key2': []}, {'key1': 'path/12', 'key2': []}, {'key1': 'path/123', 'key2': []}]
```

As an alternative you could use a *normal* Python function, as below:

```
def key(d):
    return len(d["key1"])


res = sorted(jobs, key=key)
print(res)
```

**Setup**

```
jobs = [{"key1": "path/123", "key2": []}, \
        {"key1": "path/12", "key2": []}, \
        {"key1": "path/1", "key2": []}]
```